# How to change "Category" in Oreo onwards notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

Below is the Settings screen of Facebook app. In my app it displays "Category", here it is "Kalis Martinez". I want to achieve that in my app.

[image]

What my app is displaying is as below:

[image]

**What I am doing is as below.**

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannelGroup(new 
NotificationChannelGroup(groupId, groupName));

String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL";

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), SECONDARY_CHANNEL)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            //build summary info into InboxStyle template
            .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
                    .addLine("Alex Faarborg  Check this out")
                    .addLine("Jeff Chang    Launch Party")
                    .setBigContentTitle("2 new messages")
                    .setSummaryText("janedoe@example.com"))
            //specify which group this notification belongs to
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
            //set this notification as the summary for the group
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon())
            .setAutoCancel(true);

manager.notify(id, notification.build());
```

`setGroup()` and `setGroupSummary()` do grouping while displaying notifications in System tray.

How to change that label?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for create a notification Group to change title like this

```
// The id of the group.
String groupId = "my_group_01";
// The user-visible name of the group.
CharSequence groupName = getString(R.string.group_name);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(new NotificationChannelGroup(groupId, groupName));
```

Or check about [Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#java)

Comment: I am doing that just after creating notificationManager instance. But its not working. Is there any change while creating channel too?

Comment: I have posted that above in the question.